# Is there a way to get a list of Azure AD tenants from within a service principal?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created an app to get various information from Azure AD, such as users and groups. It lives in one of my tenants as an app registration. This works fine, but now I would also like my app to get a list of the ids of other tenants I have in my account.

I have given my app user_impersonation permission on Azure Service Management, and I am able to make
`GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01` requests using my client credentials. However, when I make that call I get a list only containing the tenant that my app/service principal lives in. Is there a way I can use this API call to see other tenant ids from within my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do that with auth code flow instead of client credentials flow.

Since you are trying to get the tenants of your account rather than the app/service principal, you have to include the account information when doing the authentication.

Client credentials flow is App-only. Auth code flow is App+user.

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#authorization-code-grant-interactive-clients) to learn how to implement Authorization code grant (interactive clients).

And here is the document about OAuth 2.0 [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

You need to [Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) first and then [Request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) with the code from the previous step. Using this access token, you can list the tenants you have in your account.